# (Deck.GL - Trips Layer ) How can I set a right loop number for various route lengths?

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I am trying to render a specific path on deck gl map, but every time, I fail to set the loop correctly.

Either loop is short and the trip stops in the middle of the road, or the loop is too long and the trip makes ugly straight line from the last coordinate to the first and starts the drawing again.

I need the trip to stop at the last coordinate and smoothly start again.

```js
  const [animation] = useState({});
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [loopLength, setLoopLength] = useState(0);
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(Date.now());

  // update loop length and render layers when routes change (when api returns a response)
  useEffect(() => {
    reset();
    if (routes.length) {
      const maxRoute = max(routes, ({ timestamps }) => max(timestamps));
      setLoopLength(maxRoute);
      // setLoopLength(10000);
      setTime(0);
      setStartTime(Date.now());
    }
  }, [routes]);

  //
  useEffect(() => {
    if (routes.length) {
      animate();
    }
  }, [startTime]);

  // start animation
  const animate = () => {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(animation.id);
    const timestamp = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;
    const loopTime = loopLength / SPEED; // how many units is whole loop
    const time = ((timestamp % loopTime) / loopTime) * loopLength;
    setTime(time);
    animation.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };
  // method for rendering layers
  const renderLayers = () => {
    return [
      new TripsLayer({
        id: "trips",
        data: routes,
        getPath: (d) => d.routes,
        getTimestamps: (d) => d.timestamps,
        getColor: () => DEFAULT_THEME.trailColor0,
        opacity: 1,
        widthMinPixels: 1,
        widthScale: 0.5,
        rounded: true,
        trailLength: 1000,
        currentTime: time,
      }),
    ];
  };
```

Docs : https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/trips-layer

Example: https://deck.gl/examples/trips-layer/

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Comment: I didn't find the direct solution, but I found a workaround. Instead of passing 1 route (from start to finish) to the deckGL, I seperated this route into smaller routes and made DeckGL draw one route when the route before was finished.

For example, if I have a route A-D, instead of passing dircetly A-D to the DeckGL. I passed A-B, B-C and C-D, and made B-C start drawing when A-B was finished. and C-D when B-C was finished.